# Adjusting (rather than resampling) audio in a video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I recorded a live stream using OBS, and my audio sample rate was set to 44.1KHz. Unfortunately, OBS interpreted my device's audio input as being 48KHz, so there's a lot of glitchiness and the audio is pitched about 9% higher (which was the case during the stream itself, although none of the viewers realized this was going on at the time).

Is there a way to use FFMpeg or similar to change the sample rate of the audio stream (and probably remux it), without trying to resample the audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this answer while searching myself.

What you need is the filter [`asetrate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-asetrate).

Example usage `ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a copy -af 'asetrate=44100' output.flac`

Comment: That command failed to run with an error below.
    Filtergraph 'asetrate=44100' was defined for audio output stream 0:0 but codec copy was selected.
    Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

Comment: the fix for that would be to use the corresponding "codec", like `pcm_s16le` if the input was a typical wav file. just `ffprobe` the input and copy what it says for the stream's format